# URL Rewriting on Localhost? Apache PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache mod_rewrite on Xampp on my local machine but the code doesnt seem to work.

Please look at the code below and assist me. I'm a beginner with this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteRule     ^m3/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$/?profile=com_frontpage&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I want is the URL below:

```
http://localhost/m3/?profile=com_frontpage&url=nero
```

to be rewritten as

```
http://localhost/m3/nero
```

Please help me achieve this.

Thanx

Thanks for your quick responses

I have implemented the revised code given but once I try to enter the new URL I keep getting a 404 error.

I am using Xampp on a Windows OS so renaming the file to .htaccess is being rejected and I am not sure using 'htaccess.txt' is working.

What could be the issue?

Thanx

Comment: Where do you use that rule? By the way, the pattern and replacement of the `RewriteRule` directive must be separated by at least one space or tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this if your `.htaccess` file is located in the site root (in the `htdocs` folder):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m3/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ m3/index.php?profile=com_frontpage&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, you need to save your file as `.htaccess`. Just "Save As..." from whatever editor you're using and save the file as `.htaccess`. The only place that you can't do this from is within Windows Explorer, but that's just Explorer being stupid; you definitely can save the file with the correct name from a program (even Notepad).

Or, if you prefer, you can do it from command line:

```
cd C:\path\to\xampp\htdocs\
rename htaccess.txt .htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `RewriteBase`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /m3/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?profile=com_frontpage&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

EDIT: Fixed syntax.

Comment: I have changed the code I have but I am still getting a 404 error what could be the issue.

Comment: I've edited my above sample as I realised there was no space in your `RewriteRule`, meaning a pattern was not being matched. Try the above now.

Comment: Thanx for that I didnt know about the spacing issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this option set in your document root directory in Apache's httpd.conf file:

```
AllowOverride All
```